# Qt mainwindow handle space key press

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, keyevent

I am programming a Qt programm and I want to get triggered, when the user presses Space, but it doesn't work.

**mainwindow.h**

```
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
```

**mainwindow.m**

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    qDebug() << event->key();
}
```

Nearly every key is working, except for the space.

Could it be possible that the space isn't working, because there is some focus to an UI Element, if yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: Focus on an UI element alone is not enough. It must be focus on an UI element, which eats specifically space keys. But a UI element, which eats space keys, should do something when you press space.

Comment: How can I loose the focus on this UI element? I have some buttons and textedits, which will of course eats the space keys.

Comment: QWidget * QApplication::focusWidget() gets you the widget, which has the keyboard focus. void QWidget::clearFocus() takes the focus from this widget.

Comment: Eventually you could set ``Qt::NoFocus`` to child widgets. The problem is, a lot of widgets accept space (checkbox trigger for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uielement->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);` is one solution

or

`QApplication::focusWidget()` with some kind of `clearFocus()`